# TypeScript 5.0 decorator doesn't work when `noUnusedParameters` is enabled and the context is unused

Tags: typescript, decorator, typescript-decorator

I am trying to update a decorator for TypeScript 5.0.

```
function Serializable(target: new (...args: never) => unknown, context: unknown) {
    register(target.prototype, target.name);
}
```

The decorator registers a class for serialization. My issue lies with the `context` parameter. When `noUnusedParameters` is enabled, TypeScript throws an error since the argument is unused. If I remove the argument, any usage of decorator throws an error since the decorator is called with too many arguments.

Keeping the `context` parameter:

```
decorator.ts:1:52 - error TS6133: 'context' is declared but its value is never read.

1 export function Serializable(target: Instantiable, context: unknown) {
```

Removing the `context` parameter:

```
index.ts:3:2 - error TS1238: Unable to resolve signature of class decorator when called as an expression.
  The runtime will invoke the decorator with 2 arguments, but the decorator expects 1.

3 @Serializable
```

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: The issue is not related to version 5 or decorators. It applies to any function or method since the `noUnusedParameters` option has been added, in TypeScript 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

If a function signature requires some parameters but the actual implementation does not use all of them, name the unused parameters `_1`, `_2`, `_3` and so on. If there is only one unused parameter you can name it just `_`.

This is a convention to tell the TypeScript compiler to not complain about those parameters not being unused.

*(I don't know how I learned this, it was 5 years ago. I would like to provide a link to an official documentation backing up this knowledge but I don't have one.)*

The issue is not related to version 5 or decorators. It applies since forever (probably since TypeScript 2.0), for any function or method.